# Date subtraction leading to "TypeError: cannot perform truediv with this index type datetimeindex"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to subtract a date from a date column and calculating difference in terms of months:

```
pd.to_datetime('2020-01-20')-pd.to_datetime(df['date'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M')
```

But I get

```
> TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type datetimeindex
```

How could I correct my code in order to find the difference in months?

Comment: I think the problem is that you cannot perform arithmetic on the type that is returned by "pd.to_datetime('')". You would need to find a workaround, maybe python has methods to convert the time into a value you can perform math with, the thing I am thinking of is converting to unix time then dividing the difference by the number of seconds in a month

Comment: The expression makes no sense to me. Why are you trying to divide a date-time by months?

Comment: So could you please suggest as to what you would recommend to find `difference between a date and a date column from dataframe in terms of months` @AndrewAllaire? Would be happy to learn !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a pair of parentheses:

```
(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-20')-pd.to_datetime(df['date'])) / pd.to_timedelta(`1min')

^                                                       ^
this                                             and this
```

Comment: That was what I needed, Thanks @Quang Hoang !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short workaround using UNIX timestamps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = (pd.Timestamp('2020-01-20'))
y = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-20')
print(f"Approximately {int((x.value - y.value)/2592000/ (10 ** 9))} months have passed.")
```

Note: I changed the second date since you are taking it from the df and we don't know what the df value is.
Output
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Richard J Yu, I am considering dataframe column in my line of code, so subtracting `date column` from a date